# Get logs between two dates according to file name

Tags: linux, bash, logging

How can I get all the log files between two dates, my log file name contains the creation date: 
 
`x-node0-1-22.09.2018` => created in 22.09.2018. 
 
Thanks in advance

Comment: pick a date example without confusing. like `25.07.2017` or `07.25.2017`. who knows `07.09` is which month?

Comment: your input date ranges must be in same dateformat? `dd.mm.yyyy`?

Comment: yes, e.g, all files between 01.11.2018 and 10.01.2019

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1|awk -F'[-.]' -v from='01.08.2018' -v to='01.10.2018' 
    '{split(from,f);from=f[3]f[2]f[1];
        split(to,t);to=t[3]t[2]t[1];
        d=$NF$(NF-1)$(NF-2)}d>=from&&d<=to'
```

this line should work.

#### Note:

- since your example filename doesn't cotain any special chars, I was lazy and used `ls` result as input. It is not recommended.
- you can change the `from` and `to` parameters.
- execute the command under your log file directory.

#### test with some data

```
kent$  ls -1
x-node0-1-22.08.2018
x-node0-1-22.09.2018
x-node0-1-31.08.2018
x-node0-1-31.10.2018

kent$  ls -1|awk -F'[-.]' -v from='01.08.2018' -v to='01.10.2018' '{split(from,f);from=f[3]f[2]f[1];split(to,t);to=t[3]t[2]t[1];d=$NF$(NF-1)$(NF-2)}d>=from&&d<=to'
x-node0-1-22.08.2018
x-node0-1-22.09.2018
x-node0-1-31.08.2018
```

Comment: thank you, did you tried the code? it doesn't work for me

Comment: @Rawhi I tested with some test data. what do you mean `doesn't work` ?

Comment: @Rawhi added testing with some data

Answer (score -1):

You can use awk command like the following example which reads logs from Jan 21 - Jan 22 on syslog

---

/var/log$ awk '/Jan 21/,/Jan 22/' syslog

---

You can read more on the following link:
https://coderwall.com/p/ueazhw/parsing-logs-with-awk